# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Getting Parse Exception

Tags: java, parsing, date-format, simpledateformat

I am doing some work in my application with date formates and getting below error :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon May 02 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016" (at offset 0)
```

But, I could not parse the date : "Mon May 02 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016"

Will anybody know the date format for above date so that, I could pass it as a parameter in SimpleDateFormat ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have forgotten to set the English locale (error offset above is zero so the exception tells you that parsing "Mon" fails):

Following code has been successfully tested by me:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String input = "Mon May 02 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016";
Date d = sdf.parse(input);
```